# Correctly create a multipolygon column with postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Im new uing postgres and postgis Im using postgis v2.0.
I have a database already working with postgis and want restore data from a backup, using the next line:

```
pg_restore -U db_user -d db_name -C backupfile.backup
```

I get next error:

```
sql:import.sql:53: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 19:     geom public.geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
```

I was able to get the sql code and if I execute it I get the same error, of course :),
and the sql code is:

```
CREATE SCHEMA ch01;


ALTER SCHEMA ch01 OWNER TO db_user;

SET search_path = ch01, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

CREATE TABLE geotable (
    ...
    geom public.geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
);  

...
```

Can you help me? Which is the correct way to create this table with this required column? Note that this table is not created in public schema where geometry type is, it is asked to be created in ch01 schema instead, I think this could be the problem but I really dont know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you restoring from a different version of PostGIS? If it is installed in `public`, it is a really good idea to keep it in the search path, thus `SET search_path = ch01, public, pg_catalog;`

Comment: True, it is always a good idea to set the search_path correctly, however, that is not the main issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
create table ch01.geotable(
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)
);
```

It is the table, not the column, that belongs in the schema ch01. You can, of course, grant access rights to particular user(s) after table creation to. The geometry functions are installed by default in the schema public, so that they are generally available to anyone with access rights to that database -- your error comes from putting schema.datatype in the create table statement.

See the official docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html for more on schemas, users, etc.